# Factories calling their own functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've recently ran into a factory that vaguely resembles the one shown below:

```
.factory("MyFactory", ['$interval', function($interval) {
    var factoryObj;

    factoryObj.setCheckupTime = function(intervalMs) {
        var checkupInterval = $interval(function() {
            // do checkup logic...
        }, intervalMs);
    };

    factoryObj.setCheckupTime(60000);

    return factoryObj;

}]);
```

The problem is the line right before the return:

```
factoryObj.setCheckupTime(60000);
```

This line feels wrong because we're making a singleton perform an action on itself automatically instead of by some dependent unit of code.

I wanted to get others' opinions on the matter; does this go formally go against any of Angular's best practices, or maybe any rules on how Singletons are supposed to be used?

I was also unsure how to describe this problem as I've never ran into it; is there another term/terminology for what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, is it a bad idea declaring a factory that self starts it's own thing when it's built by angular's core not telling anybody that something has started in the process?

Yes, that's really bad! Is really difficult to maintain and track problems when things are done automatically especially on angular factory that is an internal behavior.

I recommend starting it manually from somewhere that you can track and understand it in the future.

Comment: Oh I didn't know it was only called when required not when injected.  That doesn't change my question much though; the factory is still calling it's own function before being told to do so by something that depends on it.

Comment: Well, as I said. Your function is just a constructor. The problem with your example is not the function being called by it self but the fact that the `init` function is being exposed to the factory object. Most style guide recomend organizing things to prevent maintainability problems your example is just a bad example. I'll update my answer with a propper example.

Comment: I don't really understand how my example is a bad example.  In the actual codebase I'm working with now, there's a factory similar to the one I showed in my example, except the init function in my case is actually a function that takes in a time as ms as an argument as uses that to create an $interval with the specified delay.  The function should still be exposed to the factory object because we want other people to set their own interval on it, but automatically sets one up by default.

Comment: Well, that's why it's a bad example. This pattern with an `init` method, where it's suposed to be the `constructor` of your object, shouldn't expose his own constructor as a public method, especially in this case. There is no problem calling a self function inside the factory declaration, it could be part of your initialization. The problem is to expose a method that shouldn' be on the interface of your object when it's not part for his behavior.

Comment: Anyway I hope that I could help somehow :)

Comment: Could you look at my edit?  Hopefully that helps clarify what I'm working with.

Comment: I'm very sorry for you mate. This code looks terrible. I'll make some updates on my current example that I think will help you on a better aproach.

Comment: Thanks.  Like I said, I didn't write it myself.  Need a better reason to change it than just "it's terrible" :)

Comment: Well, take a look at my example under UPDATE 1. I think you can use this as a reference to your actual code. This way you can protect (encapsulate) the member of the object properly. Hope that I've helped you.

Comment: Yes that does help, thank you.  It doesn't technically answer my question though.  It's still an angular factory that's performing an action on it self without anything other than angular telling it to do that action.  Isn't that bad?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my answer with a proper conclusion about this issue.

Comment: Yes I just saw that, perfect!  If you could remove everything but the conclusion section I will accept the answer.  The other information isn't particularly necessary to the question in my opinion.  I will update my question as well to be more succinct.  Thank you again.